# Duplicate records are allowed in table with two primary keys

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table "UserDetails" in which two columns namely "EmailId" and "UserId" are set as primary key. However I don't get any key violation from the SQL engine when I try to insert duplicate values in to the table. How do I debug this?

Screenshots :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have two primary keys, you have a composite primary key where two columns are considered the primary key.

This means that both columns **together** must be unique.  Your current screenshot shows that while two records have the same email, the respective rows have different userid's, thus the primary (composite) key is unique between the two, because both the emailid and userid are not the same between the two records.

Read more about composite keys [here](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/08/23/composite_primary_keys.aspx)

EDIT:  I'm not entirely certain what you're trying to accomplish, but my guess is you would want userid to be the primary key, and have emailid be a unique field.